# Is it possible to get list of features/variables used in model after saving model file using joblib.dump?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means, joblib

I had built scikit-learn kmeans model and had dumped it using joblib.dump command. Now I want to test it with new set of data, but not able to recall features that were used in building. Could anyone help with which model attribute/function would give me list of features/variable that was used during model building?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use exactly the same variables and pre-processing steps to create the features for the model to use. This information is an artifact of your preprocessing pipeline, and is not stored in model. Therefore it cannot generally be recovered from the picked model.

Use source code control (like git) to keep track of your preprocessing code and model setup.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My bad, I did not documented workflow properly.